# Should there be an explanation of community wiki in the parent site faq?

Tags: discussion, questions

Currently I can find no mention of what community wiki is or when a question should be marked as such.  Should there be some explanation of that?

Comment: I think we need to first decide if questions that invite discussions are or are not on topic. When it comes to SEO, almost everything is a discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a general issue of how to propagate all the posts tagged `faq` from meta.stackoverflow out to the other Stack Exchange sites. Whatever we decide will serve as a general user guide for the Stack Exchange engine for all the sites.